# Sencha Touch DataView inside of Ext.Menu

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a `DataView` that lists a bunch of `component.DataItems`. While I have no problem displaying this list of items in a NavigationView, I can't seem to display them inside of an `Ext.Menu`

```
Ext.define('AIN.view.MyDataView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'channellist',
config: {
    defaultType: 'mylistitem',
    useComponents: true
},
});
```

This is the menu that I need to display the DataItems

```
Ext.define('AIN.view.SlideNavigation', {
requires: ['Ext.Menu'],
singleton: true,
constructor: function(config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
},
layout : 'fit',
width  : 250,
setMenu: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.createMenu('left'), {
        side: 'left',
        reveal: true
    });

    Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.createMenu('right'), {
        side: 'right',
        reveal: true
    });
},

createMenu: function(side) {

    var items = [
        //Components need to be displayed here (I think)
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Latest News',
            iconCls: 'star',
            scope: this,
            handler: function() {
                 AIN.container.setActiveItem(0);
                 Ext.Viewport.hideMenu(side);
            }
        },
    ];

    var className = 'Ext.Menu';

    return Ext.create(className, {


        items: items
    });
}
});
```

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was a pretty simple fix, I couldn't have both that button item and the list inside of var items. If the button is in there then the list didn't show up. So the fix was removing this code.

```
    {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Latest News',
        iconCls: 'star',
        scope: this,
        handler: function() {
             AIN.container.setActiveItem(0);
             Ext.Viewport.hideMenu(side);
        }
    },
```

and adding this code instead

```
    {
        xclass: 'AIN.view.MyDataView',
        store: 'TestStore'
    }
```